# How do I define RadioListTitles horizontally?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

can you help me with my problem?  My app have 2 RadioListTitle, they are located vertically, but I need to locate them horizontally. How to do it?

```
RadioListTile(
        title: const Text('Мужской'),
        value: GenderList.male,
        groupValue: _gender,
        onChanged: (GenderList value) {setState(() { _gender = value;});},
      ),

       RadioListTile(
        title: const Text('Женский'),
        value: GenderList.female,
        groupValue: _gender,
        onChanged: (GenderList value) {setState(() { _gender = value;});},
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it with Row and Expanded

```
Row(
 children:[
  Expanded(child: RadioListTile(...) ),
  Expanded(child: RadioListTile(...) ),
 ],
)
```